# основы PHP замена ключей с помощью array_flip

Tags: php

Коллеги программисты, добрый день нужна Ваша помощь.

Обработчик строк *strtr* заменяет ключи на их значение, а наоборот осуществляется при помощи *array_flip*, но у меня не выходит подскажите как с помощью *array_flip* обратно поменять местами значение на их ключи?

Пример кода:

```
<?php
$code = array (

    'н' => '1',
    'а' => '2',
    'п' => '3',
    'л' => '4',
    'р' => '5'
);

    $text = 'нас предали явка провалена.';

$cipher = strtr($text, $code);


echo "Оригинал: ($text)<br/> Шифровка: ($cipher)<br/>";

$rash = array_flip($cipher);

echo "Расшифровка: ($rash)";
```

вывод:

> Оригинал: (нас предали явка провалена.)
>   Шифровка: (12с 35ед24и явк2 35ов24е12.)
>
> WARNING array_flip() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given on
>   line number 18 Расшифровка: ()

Comment: `strtr` возвращает строку..... соответственно у вас в `$cipher` - строка ....... и вам об этом и говорят, что вы подставляете строку, а не массив........соответственно... вам нужно иметь массив обратный `$code`, а в переменную `$rash` сложить строку таким же способом, как и в `$cipher` только в качестве входной строки дать `$cipher`, а вместо заменяемых символов - тот обратный массив

Comment: @АлексейШиманский на примере кода плиз)

Comment: Ну а что, я разве как-то невнятно объяснил?

Comment: разбирал ваше объяснение по словам... и все получилось.

Comment: спасибо $rash = array_flip($code);
$otv = strtr($text, $rash);

Comment: Ну вот. отлично. Только в `$otv = strtr($text, $rash);` должен быть не `$text`, а `$cipher`.....  Если тот обратный массив (который обратный массиву `$code`) не будет использоваться нигде, то тогда можно сразу написать `$rash = strtr($cipher, array_flip($code));`